# VBA Send selection by email failing

Tags: vba, excel, selection

I have a workbook with two worksheets. Sheet "Tickets" is a list which includes a manager userid in the first column and some other data in the other 3 columns. Sheet "Email_List" contains the manager userid, email address, and first name.

I want the script to use the userid to select the rows in "Tickets" relevant to each manager in "Email_List" and email that selection to just that manager.

The selection section seems to be working, and the email to relevant manager seems to be working, but rather than just sending the selection; the whole "Tickets" sheet is being sent.

EDIT: Upon further investigation, it works when all the matching user IDs are in a single block of consecutive rows. So a workaround would be to sort the UserID column before running the this script.

```
Sub SendSelection()

Dim Sendrng As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim rCell As Range
Dim rRng As Range
Dim lRow As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim StartCell As Range
Dim rRng2 As Range

'Set up the range to base the selection on
Set sht = Sheets("Tickets")
Set StartCell = Range("A1")

lRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row

Set rRng2 = sht.Range("A1:A" & lRow)

i = 1
'set it to loop through each the user ids
Do While Sheets("Email_List").Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
'look through cells in first column of data in "Tickets"
For Each rCell In rRng2
    'If the userids match, then...
    If rCell.Value = Sheets("Email_List").Cells(i, 1).Value Then
        'set initial rRng to the first matched cell and the rest of the row
        If rRng Is Nothing Then
                Set rRng = Range(rCell, rCell.Offset(0, 3))
            'then add subsequent matched cells/rows to rRng
            Else
                Set rRng = Application.Union(rRng, Range(rCell, rCell.Offset(0, 3)))
        End If
    End If
Next
'select the range of matched data
rRng.Select
'set the selection as the range of data to be sent
Set Sendrng = Selection

'Create the mail and send it
With Sendrng

    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
    With .Parent.MailEnvelope

        .Introduction = "TEST ONLY"

        With .Item
            'get email address from "Email_List"
            .To = Sheets("Email_List").Cells(i, 2).Value
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "**TEST**"
            .Send
        End With

    End With

End With
Set rRng = Nothing
i = i + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I simulated a few cases, and your code works fine. Did you ask the recepiants to show you what they have got ? it is preffered to modify to `Set StartCell = sht.Range("A1")` , but that's not causing what you have described

Comment: @ShaiRado Yes, I looked at what the recipients were receiving. They are all getting all of  the data on the "Tickets" worksheet in the form of a table in the body of the email. I'm struggling to see why this isn't working.. When I step through I can see that the correct cells are selected when the email is being sent.

It's like "Sendrng" is being defined as the active worksheet rather than just the selected cells

Comment: if your Range selection is only 1 Cell (which in my test was not the case), then it will send the entire sheet

Comment: In my testing there were no cases where there was only 1 cell matched.

Comment: Perhaps it's setting "Sendrng" to a single cell in the "Email_List" worksheet? Even though the step through doesn't show that sheet as the active one.

Answer (score 0):

you try with filtering "Tickets" cells by each manager ID:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SendMails()
    Dim IDRng As Range, IDCell As Range

    With Worksheets("Email_List")
        Set IDRng = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    End With

    For Each IDCell In IDRng
        With Worksheets("Tickets")
            With .Range("D1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=IDCell.Value
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then '<--| if any IDCell has been filtered
                    SendSelection .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), IDCell
                End If
            End With
        End With
    Next IDCell
End Sub

Sub SendSelection(rngToSend As Range, IDCell As Range)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    With rngToSend

        ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
        With .Parent.MailEnvelope
            .Introduction = "TEST ONLY"
            With .Item
                'get email address from "Email_List"
                .To = IDCell.Offset(, 1).Value
                .CC = ""
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = "**TEST**"
                .Send
            End With
        End With
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

note: you need to insert a header row as first row in "Tickets"

Comment: Thanks for providing the answer but I went with the workaround of sorting the data by userid. Will give this a go when I get some spare time and see if it works.